# How to change titlebar color in Delphi 10.4 FMX application?

Tags: windows, delphi, styles, firemonkey, titlebar

Why there is no property about Form TitleBar in Delphi 10.4 FMX multi-device application? (Windows 64bit application)
How to change the form TitleBar color?
I can not edit the custom or the default style for Form either.
Found a third-party site that shows some styles have colored TitleBar.
https://www.delphistyles.com/fmx/index.html
So, does anyone knows the mystery part about it?

Comment: Asking *WHY* something is the way it is, is not a good question for StackOverflow. You would have to ask Embarcadero *WHY* FMX works this way. But IMHO it doesn't make sense for there to be a Titlebar-related property because FMX is cross-platform and every platform handles windows/titles differently. In this case, Windows doesn't provide an API to change the titlebar color, it requires over-drawing the titlebar manually, which is VERY difficult to do correctly. Whether FMX styles can do that is another matter. It sounds like your *real* question is about how to use styles in FMX?

Comment: Please note that Remy isn't exaggerating when he says it is "VERY difficult". It really is. Almost every time someone tries this, he or she is making a big mistake. For instance, the RAD Studio IDE itself introduced a custom title bar in 10.3 (or somewhere near that version). The first thing I noticed when I started RAD Studio 10.3 was that the title bar disintegrated into fragments (!) when I maximized the window using Aero snap. Since then I have found many other bugs related to this.

Comment: (Meta: @Mitchell, I am a bit curious: Did you read the description of the "styles" tag when you added it?)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Delphi IDE is a VCL based application meaning it is making use of VCL styles. Now VCL styles have been buggy since the day they have been released. This is why so many people have problems with them. But OP is talking here about Firemonkey application which is using Firemonkey styles. Firemonkey styles have been pretty stable since the very beginning so I don't expect OP to have much problem on this front.

Comment: @SilverWarior: I am aware of that, and didn't intend to suggest anything else.

Comment: Thanks all for your treasure reply. 
@Remy Lebeau, you could be my stack overflow teacher. I should try to figure out FMX styles first.
Back to my stupid question, I do really not foud any property about titlebar in FMX at first. and I read some Microsoft Documents about the Title bar customization [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui2).
So, Embarcadero did not wrap those api for some reason. 
I do not have any experience and ability to wrap windows api before.
Is it possible to make it by those windows api?

Comment: @MitchellHu "*I do really not foud any property about titlebar in FMX*" - because there isn't one. "*I read some Microsoft Documents about the Title bar customization*" - FMX (and VCL) use base Win32 APIs. That titlebar API is not part of the main Win32 API, but it is accessible via WinRT, which is available to Delphi via COM interop. In any case, that document says: "*Title bar customization APIs are currently supported on Windows 11 only*", but FMX (and VCL) have been around a long time and support older Windows versions. So no, FMX does not "wrap those api", you have to access it manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, "Title bar customization APIs are currently supported on Windows 11 only". and the FMX  does not work for windows OS only. So, with Delphi 10.4 FMX and Windows 10, You say it could be accessed manually. But, without Windows APIs, How to handle the form caption area? really curious about it!!!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand you are right!!! The "Styles" is the key point. For almost a week study and try some stupid test code. have some conclusions:
1. Styles are some kind of Artwork, that must suitable for all platforms.
2. Styles files （***.vsf）for VCL could save as FMX style by  Bitmap Style Designer.

Comment: you are right!!! The "Styles" is the key point. For almost a week study and try some stupid test code. have some conclusions:
1. Styles are some kind of Artwork, that must suitable for all platforms.
2. Styles files***.vsf）for VCL could save as FMX style by Bitmap Style Designer. 
3. Part of custom Styles that have colored form caption must have a windowborderstyle layout. With Stylebook and import the Styles, you will find windowborderstyle in the Style container. With BitmapLinks Editor I realize that  Without the windows TitleBar apis why the Styles maker could make colored caption form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to edit Title bar style the style editor that is built into Delphi IDE won't be enough. The built in style designer is mostly intended to quickly create custom styles for specific components.

What you want to use is standalone Bitmap Style Designer that you launch from **Tools-> Bitmap Stlye Designer**

Comment: Use Bitmap Style Designer I create a new fmx style,
set Objects/Form/Image/Tile.Colr = clBlue
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ry2m4bkrnwglkkn/myformStyle.PNG?dl=0)
then save as myform.vsf/myform.stytle
with a stylebook, load myform.style , 
the form caption area color does not change to clBlue.why not?

Comment: Finally, I figure out how to make a custom FMX Style with colored Form TitleBar.
Just with Bitmap Style Designer, export out a style png file then modifies it with the color you desired and update it, Last step is to save it as xxx.style file, here is the FMX style with colored form TitleBar.